# Can't ingest protobuf data into influx with telegraf

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, influxdb, telegraf

I have a kafka message topic I want to ingest into influxDB. Currently, the data is in the protobuf format for performance reasons.

I tried to set up the input like this:

```
[[inputs.kafka_consumer]]
  brokers = ["kafka:19092"]
  topics = ["acc-test-topic"]
  consumer_group = "telegraf_metrics_consumers"
  max_message_len = 1000000
  data_format = "xpath_protobuf"
  xpath_protobuf_file = "/etc/telegraf/DriverInput.proto"
  xpath_protobuf_type = "DriverInput"
```

And the output like this:

```
 [[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["http://localhost:8087"]

  token = "{some token}"
  organization = "testing"
  bucket = "test-bucket"
```

Sadly I don't get any data into my influxDB

I have to admit that I have problems understanding the instruction for parsing the data with telegraf. This is the document I am using: https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/release-1.21/plugins/parsers/xpath

When I look into the kafka topic description, I can see that the data is taken from the group:

```
docker exec kafka /usr/bin/kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --describe --group telegraf_metrics_consumers
```

Will result into:

```
GROUP                      TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                   HOST            CLIENT-ID
telegraf_metrics_consumers acc-test-topic  0          -               0               -               Telegraf-acaa4b29-b9e2-ac98-9640338b325a /192.168.160.5  Telegraf
telegraf_metrics_consumers acc-test-topic  1          15849           15850           1               Telegraf-acaa4b29-b9e2-ac98-9640338b325a /192.168.160.5  Telegraf
telegraf_metrics_consumers acc-test-topic  2          48              48              0               Telegraf-acaa4b29-b9e2-ac98-9640338b325a /192.168.160.5  Telegraf
```

Can you help me find out, what I ve done wrong?

### Update

I add the docker-compose file.

```
version: '3'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.3.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    restart: always
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 3
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    depends_on:
    - zookeeper

  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.1.1
    container_name: influxdb
    ports:
      - 8087:8086
    volumes:
      - ./influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb2
    environment:
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_USERNAME=martin
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_PASSWORD=_____
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_ORG=test
      - DOCKER_INFLUXDB_INIT_BUCKET=test-bucket
  telegraf:
    container_name: telegraf
    build: ./telegraf
    volumes:
      - ./telegraf/telegraf.conf:/etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf
      - ./telegraf/DriverInput.proto:/etc/telegraf/DriverInput.proto
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
```

Comment: `kafka:19092` is in your config, but your docker command uses port 9092...?

Comment: The port is for internal use in docker. I added the docker compose file for further details. Also kafka tells me, that the consumer group is reading the data, so the connection seems to work.

Comment: Facing the same issue, did you happen to solve it ?

Comment: Sadly not. It's frustrating. I think I will use another message broker.